# When I use JNI class in VOCE c++, get an unhandled exception when the program calls FindClass()

Tags: c++, voice-recognition

I want to run the program VOCE, which is a library of speech recognition. When the program run util the code like this:

```
// Find the main Voce class by name.
jclass c = internal::gEnv->FindClass(internal::gClassName.c_str());
```

It give me the error:

```
 Unhandled exception at 0x00af1c10 in SpeechReco.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

So I go inside the code:

```
 jclass FindClass(const char *name) {
    return functions->FindClass(this, name);
}
```

And the name is "voce/interface", here it throws the exception.

Somebody knows this error and how to debug it?

Comment: Do you check if `gEnv` or `functions` is NULL?  The error clearly states you are reading a NULL pointer.